# Is it alright to contact lab members of a lab you interviewed at for an update on your PhD application?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

I am international applicant for a PhD program in Molecular Biology. I have interviewed with a professor and have had a chat with all of the members of the lab I am extremely interested in working in. It has been over 4 months since I first got in touch with the lab as of now. I am trying to be patient, but is it okay to get in touch with a current PhD student in the lab to get an update on what impression I had left on them and if the professor is going to be considering me.

This is for a graduate program in Molecular Biology in Canada.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is inappropriate to contact PhD students in the lab to ask for an update on your application status. That is because they may not be involved in the process and it looks like you're circumventing the normal flow of information trying to get something underhand.

The correct points of contact are to ask for an update are:

1. the administrative office who handles grad applications for the department.
2. the supervisor you have talked to.

Good luck!

Comment: In fact, most likely they don't have any role in the process.

Answer (score 7):

Contact the person who interviewed you, not a student. I doubt a PhD student will know anything about who is going to be made an offer.

It's perfectly fine (especially after four months) to send a short, polite email to your interviewer asking when you can expect to hear from them.